# Evaluating JSON from popular auto-suggests

Tags: javascript, json, autocomplete, jsonp, autosuggest

I was evaluating the various ways in which the big guys implement auto suggest. These are my observations.(Search string used was "ab") Questions towards the end.

Yahoo tries something like this, where the response was a JSONP. Response is readable and serves the purpose.

### Yahoo's response

```
yasearch({"q":"ab ","gprid":"Y435dN7TRFqnYqQhnBueJA","f":["k","m"],"r":[["ab de villiers",0],["ab exercises",0],["ab king pro",0],
["ab infi-net internet banking",0],["ab mujhe raat din",0],["ab workouts",0],["ab mp3",0],["ab meri bari",0],["ab ke baras",0],["ab meri baari",0]]})
```

Bing had a similar approach. Returns an "if" block, sa_inst.apiCB() seems to be a function which would process the JSON. Again response is readable and legit.

### Bing's response

```
if(typeof sa_inst.apiCB == 'function') sa_inst.apiCB({"AS":{"Query":"ab","FullResults":1,"Results":[{"Type":"AS","Suggests":[{"Txt":"ab<strong>p</strong> <strong>news</strong>","Type":"AS","Sk":""}, 
{"Txt":"ab<strong>bottapp</strong>.ab<strong>bott</strong>.<strong>in</strong>","Type":"AS","Sk":"AS1"},{"Txt":"ab<strong>t</strong> <strong>travels</strong>","Type":"AS","Sk":"AS2"},{"Txt":"ab<strong>p</strong> <strong>ananda</strong>","Type":"AS","Sk":"AS3"},
{"Txt":"ab<strong>hibus</strong>","Type":"AS","Sk":"AS4"},{"Txt":"ab<strong>p</strong> <strong>maza</strong>","Type":"AS","Sk":"AS5"},{"Txt":"ab<strong>b</strong>","Type":"AS","Sk":"AS6"},
{"Txt":"ab<strong>outgoogle</strong>","Type":"AS","Sk":"AS7"}]}]}} /* pageview_candidate */);
```

Now comes Google. Response is sent as 2 JSON objects(separated by /*""*/). Most of it is unreadable.

### Google's response

```
{e:"XteVUYKqDoKHrAfdz4D4Aw",c:0,u:"https://www.google.com/s?hl\x3den\x26gs_rn\x3d14\x26gs_ri\x3dpsy-ab\x26tok\x3dvsobDhICRmdcnY7ayKTGng\x26cp\x3d2\x26gs_id\x3dd\x26xhr\x3dt\x26q\x3dab\x26es_nrs\x3dtrue\x26pf\x3dp\x26output\x3dsearch\x26sclient
\x3dpsy-ab\x26oq\x3d\x26gs_l\x3d\x26pbx\x3d1\x26bav\x3don.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.\x26bvm\x3dbv.46751780,d.bmk\x26fp\x3d2647af89de6b6c61\x26biw\x3d1366\x26bih\x3d453\x26tch\x3d1\x26ech\x3d2\x26psi\x3dVteVUcYuzOGsB6LpgdgB.1368774484351.1",
p:true,d:"[\x22ab\x22,[[\x22ab\\u003Cb\\u003Ec\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,[]],[\x22ab\\u003Cb\\u003Ec news\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,[]],[\x22ab\\u003Cb\\u003Eercrombie\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,[]],[\x22ab\\u003Cb\\u003Ecya\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,[]]],
{\x22j\x22:\x22d\x22,\x22q\x22:\x22t8z6h8KhWvbkEX6xablxgYxDUq4\x22,\x22t\x22:
{\x22bpc\x22:false,\x22tlw\x22:false}}]"}
/*""*/{e:"XteVUYKqDoKHrAfdz4D4Aw",c:-1,u:"https://www.google.com/searchdata?hl\x3den\x26gs_rn\x3d14\x26gs_ri\x3dpsy-ab\x26tok\x3dvsobDhICRmdcnY7ayKTGng\x26cp\x3d2\x26gs_id\x3dd\x26xhr\x3dt\x26q\x3dab\x26es_nrs\x3dtrue
\x26pf\x3dp\x26output\x3dsearch\x26sclient\x3dpsy-ab\x26oq\x3d\x26gs_l\x3d\x26pbx\x3d1\x26bav\x3don.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.\x26bvm\x3dbv.46751780,d.bmk\x26fp\x3d2647af89de6b6c61\x26biw\x3d1366\x26bih\x3d453\x26tch\x3d1\x26ech\x3d2\x26psi\x3dVteVUcYuzOGsB6LpgdgB.1368774484351.1",
p:true,d:"{\x22snp\x22:1}"}/*""*/
```

1. Are those hex codes or what do you call them?
2. Why is there a need for 2 objects to be returned?
3. What is the need for encoding the JSON?
4. Which is the ideal format for JSON among these three?

Any thoughts on this are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**Are those hex codes or what do you call them?**

Assuming you are referring to Google's response, I believe they are;

the \x00 format represents hex values

the \u0000 format represents unicode values

**Why is there a need for 2 objects to be returned?**

Not sure, one guess is that one of those objects is a list of recommendations, and ther other is a list of previous searches you have made.

**What is the need for encoding the JSON?**

Basically, these guys would have needed a way of delivering structured data from their server to the client. Only two real possibilities come to mind; XML and JSON. In this case, JSON would probably always be the winner as it uses less bandwidth and can be dealt with in Javascript easier.

**Which is the ideal format for JSON among these three?**

This is only opinion, but following from above, the *ideal* situation is the least amount of data, so based on that alone, I think Yahoo wins.